# positive operators

Tags: hilbert-spaces, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Consider two Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$ and a bounded operator $T$ on $H\oplus K$. I know that there is a theorem which says the following:

$T\ge 0$ (in the operator sense) if and only if $T$ can be represented as
$$T=\begin{pmatrix} A & \sqrt{A} V \sqrt{D} \\ \sqrt{D} V^* \sqrt{A} & D \end{pmatrix}$$
for positive $A,D$ and $\|V\|\le 1$.

I am interested in the proof of this theorem (more precisely, in the exact structure of the $V$ in question). I would be very grateful for a reference to this result. I've heard it should be in Foias, Frazho, "The Commutant Lifting Approach to Interpolation Problems", but I cannot find it there...

Comment: It's easy to check that such a $T$ is positive. Conversely, I think we can just define $V$ by this formula, and then check that $\|V\|\le 1$ (with maybe some mild technical issues when $A,D$ are not invertible).